# Load more button - post per page

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on load more button and so far it's going great, but I want to know is it possible to have 10 items showing on homepage and only loading 4 per click. In my template I have this:

```
$args = array (
        'post_type' => 'case_studies',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
```

In my functions.php I have the same thing, only posts_per_page is '4', but on load it duplicates some items if posts per page numbers aren't equal. When I put same numbers, like 5 and 5, it works great. Is there any way to solve this, or these numbers must be the same?

Comment: Hi ! Can you provide us the full code of your page and the database query ?

Comment: "is it possible to have 10 items showing on homepage and only loading 4 per click"...yes, certainly that would be possible in theory. But we can't give you specific advice about how to achieve it, because we know almost nothing about your current implementation. We only have a description of your code, not enough actual code, context or data. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance.